# Stop MATLAB from changing image scale in different directions?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am plotting a 3D plot in MATLAB, and I noticed that the scale is different in each direction. In the attached image for example, you can see that the length in the z-dir is 20 which seems to be equal to the length in the y-dir whose valus is actually 6. So, how can I stop matlab from changing the scale and producing the plot with its actual scale?

[image: mode shape]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
axis equal
```

Axis documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html).